# Chrome DevTools pages dark theme

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, dark-mode

Is there way for the devTools pages (chrome://inspect) to use the dark theme ?
Chrome is Dark, my DevTool is dark but not theses few pages.

[image]

Comment: Not really, it's common for all Chromium browsers, report it as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings (in image , top right corner), then choose preferences, then choose theme, then Dark. See Image
[Google Chrome Inspection: Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMO6f.png)

Comment: That's the DevTools, I'm talking about the browsers pages.

Comment: Can you explain what is browser pages ?

Comment: Go to `chrome://inspect` in your Chrome.